# Generalizing the clutching construction to more contractible open sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

In computing the topological $K$-theory of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ I had an idea to mimic the clutching construction: Recall that this says that for the open cover $S^k = D^k_+\cup D^k_-$ a rank $n$ vector bundle over $S^k$ is uniquely specified by the homotopy class of a map $f: S^{k-1} = D^k_+\cap D^k_- \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

For $\mathbb{R}P^2$, I thought about using the open cover $\mathbb{R}P^2 = U_0 \cup U_1 \cup U_2$ where $U_i = \{[x_0, x_1, x_2] \mid x_i \neq 0\} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, hence contractible. Then one gets trivial vector bundles over these sets, and on the intersection a map $f: U_0 \cap U_1 \cap U_2\to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. I think I can compute the homotopy type of this intersection, but it is the map the other way I have trouble with, as we now have to demand some kind of compatability also on $U_i \cap U_j$.

So the question is what kind of data do we need to reconstruct the bundle, and is this something we can reasonably compute with homotopy theoretic tools?

Note: I am not just interested in the $K$-theory of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, but in computing it in this manner (or for other types of spaces for which a construction like this is feasible).

Apologies for the vagueness of the question, and I appreciate any help and clarification!

Comment: You'll typically need transition functions on the three overlaps, such that they satisfy cocycle conditions. And yes, I'd say this is definitely a reasonable way of computing the K-theory.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Yes, I figured something like that. Can that be packaged conveniently in some way?

Comment: Definitely! If a space $X$ has a cover $U_i$ by contractible spaces, then to describe a vector bundle on $X$ you need to describe transition maps $U_i \cap U_j \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying cocycle conditions. Although I'm too fuzzy on the details right now, I think this can be neatly captured in terms of Cech cohomology.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Yes, this seems like the right approach. I will try to see what I can deduce from Čech cohomology.

Comment: In general, you should be able to package this information into a Mayer-Vietoris spectral sequence for generalized theories.  See, e.g., Segal's "Classifying spaces and spectral sequences".

Comment: I think this is talked about in Karoubi's book on K - theory. Maybe ctrl + f "cocycle condition"